# DOM objects over other DOM objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a problem placing DOM elements.

In this HTML (http://bluecodestudio.com/scripts/), a pop up appears, animated thanks to the javascript. After I press the 'Enter' button, I'd like that the 'Welcome' message is placed in the center.

But it 'collides' with the other elements, and I can't find the way to make it 'float/flow' over the elements. Any changes to my style.css to fix it? Thanks!

PS: I use absolute path routes for [the links of] the scripts and the stylesheet because I use a Nodejs module which kind of 'forces' me to do that, or at least is the easiest way to make it work.

Edit: CSS direct link: http://bluecodestudio.com/scripts/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
 #welcomeContent
 {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       z-index: 1; /*For overlapping divs*/
       opacity: 0; /*Not visible on load*/
 }

 #welcomeMessage
 {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

This in theory should put your message in the center of parent div. you'll need a z-index since this will overlap divs

Comment: I managed to make it 'work', more or less. I had to add some 'position:relative', because "z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)."

But after I press the 'Enter' button, and the 'loginContent' fadesOut, the 'welcomeContent' won't fadeIn; I don't know if it's because of the CSS or the Javascript..

Comment: This is my final CSS:

#loginContent {
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;
}

#welcomeContent {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 88px 0;
 text-align: center;
 height: 200px;
 width: 400px;
 z-index:0;
}

Comment: The welcome message wasn't appearing because I was using z-index:-1, which hide it behind the 'pop up'/div, I guess. It's my first time using z-index. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

give your white div a `position: relative;`
then give your welcome p the following css:

```
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
line-height: #px; // same as the white div
```

i think that should do the trick

edit:

I did not look into the depths previously. I just tried it in the chrome inspector and you should replace your css with this:

```
#welcomContent {
position: absolute;
padding: 88px 0;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: he said that he cannot make it `position: relative` in his post - as you're pretty new, I won't vote it down

Comment: @Zachary thanks, but where does he say that? My english is not that great but i realy can't make that up from his post...

Comment: "PS: I use absolute path routes for the scripts and the stylesheet because I use a Nodejs module which kind of 'forces' me to do that, or at least is the easiest way to make it work."

Comment: But Zach, I meant that the scripts and the stylesheet urls are an absolute path!

I didn't say a word about the position:absolute/relative!

Sorry if I didn't explain it well.

Comment: doesn' that refer to the "http://bluecodestudio.com/scripts/kiposgift.js" he uses in stead of the relative path "/scripts/kiposgift.js". He could easily add #menuWindow {position: relative} somewhere in his css, or am i realy seeing this wrong?

Comment: thanks David, I guessed that was what you meant already; I won't vote you down for it Zachary ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant Peter!

I tried with position:relative, but I'm possibly doing it wrong..

The CSS is this one: http://bluecodestudio.com/scripts/style.css

Comment: If I just make the changes you said, I'm not able to select the text input at all, neither to click the 'Enter' button.. :(

Comment: Nevermind it, I got it to work thanks to the z-index that ExceptionLimeCat suggested! Thanks for all the help! Your method is also the one that correctly centers the 'Welcome' p, because his solution doesn't do so.

Answer (score 0):

okay so here is a pseudo jQuery solution:

```
var welcome = $(welcome);
var popupMsg = $(popupMsg);
var popup = $(popup);
var enter = $(enterButton);

enter.click(function () {
    var pOff = popup.offset();
    var newLeft = pOff.Left + ((popup.width() - welcome.width()) / 2);
    var newTop = pOff.Top + ((popup.height() - welcome.height()) / 2);

    welcome.css({ left: newLeft, top: newTop });
    popupMsg.fadeOut();
    welcome.fadeIn();
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Remember, this is just pseudo - you will have to fill it in.

Comment: I didn't got to try if this worked. Thanks anyway Zach!

Comment: No worries - glad to contribute

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're going to want to hide the `#loginContent` div with display: none when it is done fading out, then it will no longer be taken into account when determining the layout.

Then to center the welcome text horizontally take `float: left` off the `#welcomeContent` div.

If you also want to center the text vertically, there are various ways to do it, some of which are described here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/. If you are only going to have the single word Welcome!, the line-height method might be the simplest.

Comment: That 'display:none' is interesting, but what if I want to fade out the old 'data' and fade in 'the new data' at the same time?

Thanks for the info and the link, though! :)

Comment: Well, I already solved it. Thanks anyway!